Needs help with assembling the idea of engaging a DC geared motor with hanging cable spoolers
So I have these cable reels/spoolers of TRIAX camera, and I want to coil/unwind them using a geared DC motor


I want to use one DC geared motor for all of them, so I thought of making the DC geared motor detachable to use it with each one of them seperately.
This is the DC motor I have currently


Do you have any thoughts or suggestions on how to accomplish that?
I also want to ask if it's possible to pull the cable while the DC geared motor is connected to the cable reel while it's turned off.
Thanks in advance!

if it's possible to pull the cable while the DC geared motor is connected ... yes, if you design it that way

Could you please be more specific?

you are the one who asked a question that has a simple yes answer ... this is a Q&A site, not a chat forum... please write a focused, answerable question

you can use a clutch at each spool

A shaft across the back, with a chain drive picking up each reel on each side. if you think of a bicycle one way drive that would allow each to disconnect - in one direction.

@SolarMike Can you please be more detailed?

@jsotola
I meant what to use to accomplish it, I can use a clutch, but I want to detach and attach again so easily.
